# C# image extension and fill in connection

Tags: c#, asp.net

With below code i am facing an error message with connection " Connection property has not been initialized. ", i recognize the problem which is file extension name over ".jpg" and "JPEG", it would not go into "if ((filess.Except(extensions).Count()) <= 0)" TRUE branch. so , the SqlCommand would not get the connection object which be assigned inside the IF-TURE branch. I tried to fix it with several way but i couldn't so can you help me with solving this problem.  To make sure the problem is from this side i tried this code without any images and its works. Some inform me that For some reason the OP simply will not refactor the code into smaller testable blocks, but how i can fix it.

```
   protected void adNewdadsbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string FileExtentio = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FileUploadImg1.FileName);
        string FileExtentio2 = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FileUploadImg2.FileName);
        string FileExtentio3 = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FileUploadImg3.FileName);
        string FileExtentio4 = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FileUploadImg4.FileName);
        string FileExtentio5 = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FileUploadImg5.FileName);

        HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies.Get("Location");
        string Location = string.Empty;
        var user = Session["UsrNme"];
        Location = cookie.Value;

        var UsrNme = Session["UsrNme"];

        if (Session["UsrNme"] != null && cookie != null)
        {
            using (var nySqlCon = new SqlConnection(sc))
            {
                if (FileUploadImg1.HasFile || FileUploadImg2.HasFile || FileUploadImg3.HasFile || FileUploadImg4.HasFile || FileUploadImg5.HasFile)
                {

                    var filess = new[] { FileExtentio, FileExtentio2, FileExtentio3, FileExtentio4, FileExtentio5 };
                    filess = filess.Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)).ToArray();
                    var extensions = new[] { ".jpg", ".JPEG" };
                    if ((filess.Except(extensions).Count()) <= 0)
                    {

                        if (DropDownList3.SelectedValue == "no")
                        {
                            AdsWrngPanel.Visible = true;
                            adsstutslbel.Text = "- Please select ads status";
                        }
                        else
                        {

                        }


                        if (DropDownList2.SelectedValue == "no")
                        {
                            AdsWrngPanel.Visible = true;
                            adscondlbel.Text = "- Please select ads condition";
                        }
                        else
                        {

                        }

                        nySqlCon.Open();

                        SqlCommand addadscmd = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO ads (Section, Category, UID, AdsTit, AdsDesc, Country, State,AdsDate,City, AdsPrice, Img1, img2, img3, img4,img5, Wtags, Address,Condition, Status,Maker,Year,Gear,RoomNo,Space,Shower,Garage,Currency,extlink) VALUES (@Section, @Category, @UID, @AdsTit, @AdsDesc, @Country, @State,@adsDate, @City, @AdsPrice, @Img1, @img2, @img3, @img4, @img5, @Wtags, @Address,@Condition, @Status,@Maker,@Year,@Gear,@RoomNo,@Space,@Shower,@Garage,@Currency, @extlink)", nySqlCon);

                        addadscmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Section", Secdrdoads.SelectedItem.Text);
                        addadscmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Maker", makervalue);
                        addadscmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Year", Yearvalue);
                        addadscmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gear", Gearvalue);
                        addadscmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RoomNo", RoomNum);
                        addadscmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Space", areasize);
                        addadscmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Category", Catedrdoads.SelectedItem.Text);
                        addadscmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UID", user);
                        addadscmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AdsTit", addadstittxtbx.Text);
                        addadscmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AdsDesc", NyAdsDesc);
                        addadscmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Country", cookie.Value);
                        addadscmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@State", statedrdolst.SelectedItem.Text);
                        addadscmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", citiesdrdolst.SelectedItem.Text);
                        addadscmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AdsPrice", adsaddpristxtbx.Text);
                        addadscmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", addadstxtbox.Text);
                        addadscmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Shower", BathNum);
                        addadscmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Garage", garageNum);
                        addadscmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Wtags", addadswtagtxtbtn.Text);
                        addadscmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Condition", DropDownList2.SelectedItem.Text);
                        addadscmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status", DropDownList3.SelectedItem.Text);
                        addadscmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@adsDate", DateTime.Now);
                        addadscmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Currency", AddAdsCurencyLBL.Text);
                        addadscmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@extlink", extlinktxtbox.Text);


                        string imgnouser = "/images/general/nouser.jpg";

                        if (FileUploadImg1.HasFile)
                        {
                            addadscmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Img1", FileUploadImg1.FileName);
                            FileUploadImg1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/images/AdsImgs/" + FileUploadImg1.FileName));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            addadscmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Img1", imgnouser);
                        }


                        if (FileUploadImg2.HasFile)
                        {
                            addadscmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Img2", FileUploadImg2.FileName);
                            FileUploadImg2.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/images/AdsImgs/" + FileUploadImg2.FileName));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            addadscmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Img2", imgnouser);
                        }


                        if (FileUploadImg3.HasFile)
                        {
                            addadscmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Img3", FileUploadImg3.FileName);
                            FileUploadImg3.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/images/AdsImgs/" + FileUploadImg3.FileName));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            addadscmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Img3", imgnouser);
                        }


                        if (FileUploadImg4.HasFile)
                        {
                            addadscmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Img4", FileUploadImg4.FileName);
                            FileUploadImg4.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/images/AdsImgs/" + FileUploadImg4.FileName));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            addadscmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Img4", imgnouser);
                        }


                        if (FileUploadImg5.HasFile)
                        {
                            addadscmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Img5", FileUploadImg5.FileName);
                            FileUploadImg5.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/images/AdsImgs/" + FileUploadImg5.FileName));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            addadscmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Img5", imgnouser);
                        }

                        addadscmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        nySqlCon.Close();

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        AddNwAddsWrngFrmtLbl.Text = "Error: The file should have .png or .jpg format only";
                        AddNwAddsWrngFrmtLbl.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                        return;
                    }

                }

                else
                {

                    nySqlCon.Open();

                    SqlCommand addadscmdNoImg = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO ads (Section, Category, UID, AdsTit, AdsDesc, Country, State,AdsDate,City, AdsPrice, Wtags, Address,Condition, Status,Maker,Year,Gear,RoomNo, Space,Shower,Garage,extlink) VALUES (@Section, @Category, @UID, @AdsTit, @AdsDesc, @Country, @State,@adsDate, @City, @AdsPrice, @Wtags, @Address,@Condition, @Status,@Maker,@Year,@Gear,@RoomNo,@Space,@Shower,@Garage, @extlink)", nySqlCon);



                    addadscmdNoImg.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Section", Secdrdoads.SelectedItem.Text);
                    addadscmdNoImg.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Maker", makervalue);
                    addadscmdNoImg.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Year", Yearvalue);
                    addadscmdNoImg.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gear", Gearvalue);
                    addadscmdNoImg.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RoomNo", RoomNum);
                    addadscmdNoImg.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Space", areasize);
                    addadscmdNoImg.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Category", Catedrdoads.SelectedItem.Text);
                    addadscmdNoImg.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UID", user);
                    addadscmdNoImg.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AdsTit", addadstittxtbx.Text);
                    addadscmdNoImg.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AdsDesc", NyAdsDesc);
                    addadscmdNoImg.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Country", cookie.Value);
                    addadscmdNoImg.Parameters.AddWithValue("@State", statedrdolst.SelectedItem.Text);
                    addadscmdNoImg.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", citiesdrdolst.SelectedItem.Text);
                    addadscmdNoImg.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AdsPrice", adsaddpristxtbx.Text);
                    addadscmdNoImg.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", addadstxtbox.Text);
                    addadscmdNoImg.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Shower", BathNum);
                    addadscmdNoImg.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Garage", garageNum);
                    addadscmdNoImg.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Wtags", addadswtagtxtbtn.Text);
                    addadscmdNoImg.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Condition", DropDownList2.SelectedItem.Text);
                    addadscmdNoImg.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status", DropDownList3.SelectedItem.Text);
                    addadscmdNoImg.Parameters.AddWithValue("@adsDate", DateTime.Now);
                    addadscmdNoImg.Parameters.AddWithValue("@extlink", extlinktxtbox.Text);

                    addadscmdNoImg.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
                }

                MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex = 3;
                ViwMyAdsPanel.Visible = true;
                CheckUsrAds();

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where do you declare the variable _sc_ and what is its content? On which line did you get the exception?

Comment: @Steve i have declare sc before Page_load where it suppose to be and others parts of the page working fine only this code.